# How to pass variable array structure to array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I've the following variable that is dinamically created:

```
$var = "'a'=>'123', 'b'=>'456'";
```

I use it to populate an array:

```
$array=array($var);
```

I can't do `$array=array('a'=>'123', 'b'=>'456')` because $var is always different.

So it shows me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'a'=>'123', 'b'=>'456'
)
```

This is wrong, 'cause I need to get:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 123
    [b] => 456
)
```

What is wrong on my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If for whatever reason you must generate a string as `$var` in the first place.  Consider generating it as a JSON string - `{"a":"123", "b":"456"}` as you can then use standard JSON methods to convert it.

Comment: If you have control over the creation of the dynamic string, you should use JSON encoding to pass the values. Then it’s as simple as `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should just leverage PHP's syntax to populate an associative array, something like this:

```
$array = [];
$array['a'] = '123';
$array['b'] = '456';
```

However, you *could* actually write a script which parses your input to generate an associate array:

```
$var = "'a'=>'123', 'b'=>'456'";
preg_match_all ("/'([^']+)'=>'([^']+)'/", $var, $matches);
$array = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
    $array[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
}
print_r($array);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 123
    [b] => 456
)
```